# Wordpress keeps changing my link url

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

For some reason, the wordpress editor keeps changing the link to /(post-title)/(post-title)/ instead of the link I'd like it to display. I just started having this issue today.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

check your permalink settings. in the custom settings you can potentially set it to do that. It would look like "/%postname%/%postname%/" if thats the problem.